# What is Ardor and how is it different from NXT 1.x?

Tags: nxt, ardor

Ardor was recently announced as the successor to NXT 1.0 with backwards compatibility to NXT 1.x . How is it different from NXT v1.x?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From what I read Ardor claims to have every capability that NXT 1.x had but also:

1. Adds new features

"The platform offers a Decentralized Asset Exchange. Ardor will enable the trading and interaction of assets on any child chain for any of the child chain tokens. Other key features include Decentralized Voting and Governance Systems, and, Phased transactions, whereby users will be able to set multiple conditions before a transaction is executed."

2. Is easier to use

"It creates a blockchain platform that is open to everyone – from single users to fintech start-ups and governments."

"The developers assert that anyone can “create their own child chain” and interact with the entire blockchain ecosystem. The upshot is that anyone, anywhere, will be able to create blockchain services with relative ease."

3. Improves scalability

"Ardor is touted as “solving scalability problems” by separating transactions and data that do not affect security from those that do. Specifically, Ardor moves all of those that do not affect security onto child chains."

http://www.forbes.com/sites/rogeraitken/2016/06/21/nxt-crypto-blockchain-team-prepares-ardor-scalable-child-chain-platform/#40a091b6349b